# Unable to read UNICODE text file in C

Tags: c, windows, file, file-io, unicode

(I looked at previous posts and tried what they suggested but to no avail.)

I'm attempting to read in a file containing only Japanese characters. Here is what that file looks like:

わたし　わ　エドワド　オ’ハゲン　です。　これ　は　なん　です　か？

When I attempt to read it, nothing is displayed as output in the console and when debugging, the read buffer is just garbage. Here is the function I am using to read in the file:

```
wchar_t* ReadTextFileW(wchar_t* filePath, size_t numBytesToRead, size_t maxBufferSize, const wchar_t* mode, int seekOffset, int seekOrigin)
{
    size_t numItems = 0;
    size_t bufferSize = 0;
    wchar_t* buffer = NULL;
    FILE* file = NULL;

    //Ensure the filePath does NOT lead to a device.
    if (IsPathADevice(filePath) == false)
    {
        //0 indicates to read as much as possible (the max specified).
        if (numBytesToRead == 0)
        {
            numBytesToRead = maxBufferSize;
        }

        if (filePath != NULL && mode != NULL)
        {
            //Ensure there are no errors in opening the file.
            if (_wfopen_s(&file, filePath, mode) == 0)
            {
                //Set the cursor location (back to the beginning of the file by default).
                if (fseek(file, seekOffset, seekOrigin) != 0)
                {
                    //Error: Could not change file cursor position.
                    fclose(file);
                    return NULL;
                }

                //Calculate the size of the buffer in bytes.
                bufferSize = numBytesToRead * sizeof(wchar_t);

                //Create the buffer to store file data in.
                buffer = (wchar_t*)_aligned_malloc(bufferSize, BYTE_ALIGNMENT);

                //Ensure the buffer was allocated.
                if (buffer == NULL)
                {
                    //Error: Buffer could not be allocated.
                    fclose(file);
                    return NULL;
                }

                //Clear any garbage data in the buffer.
                memset(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                //Read the data from the file.
                numItems = fread_s(buffer, bufferSize, sizeof(wchar_t), numBytesToRead, file);

                //Check for read errors.
                if (numItems <= 0)
                {
                    //Error: File could not be read.
                    fclose(file);
                    _aligned_free(buffer);
                    return NULL;
                }

                //Ensure the file is closed without errors.
                if (fclose(file) != 0)
                {
                    //Error: File did not close properly.
                    _aligned_free(buffer);
                    return NULL;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

To call this function, I am doing the following. Perhaps I'm not using setlocale() correctly but from what I read it seems like I am. Just to re-iterate, the problem I'm having is that garbage seems to be read in and nothing is displayed in console:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "jp");
    wchar_t* retVal = ReadTextFileW(L"C:\\jap.txt");
    printf("%S\n", retVal);
    _aligned_free(retVal);
```

I also have the following defined at the top of my .cpp

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
```

**SOLVED:**

To fix this, as ryyker mentioned, you need to know the encoding you used to create the original file. In notepad and notepad++ there is a drop down menu for encoding. By default (and what is mostly used) is UTF-8.

Once you know the encoding you can change the read mode of _wfopen_s() to the following.

```
wchar_t* retVal = ReadWide::ReadTextFileW(L"C:\\jap.txt", 0, 1024, L"r, ccs=UTF-8");
MessageBoxW(NULL, retVal, NULL, 0);
_aligned_free(retVal);
```

You must use the message box to print foreign characters.

Comment: Are you certain about the _[encoding](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)_ of the file?  The link discusses multi-byte, et. al.

Comment: @ryyker I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am simply suggesting that you are attempting to decode a file that contains multi-byte characters, but have not yet determined exactly what encoding they are comprised of.  Look at the link I left in the previous comment.

Comment: Can you take out and post your "Solved" part as a proper answer?

Comment: I see you've found a solution!  And I just reviewed the extensive transcript of comments under @Mr.C64 's answer.  It appears Mr.C64 is really the one that answered your question.  As much as I appreciate your _accepted answer_ click, I think it should be applied elsewhere.  :)

Comment: I disagree, your answer was more concise and Mr.C64 refused to provide the solution he was suggesting me to "google" even after I asked him to provide the syntax.

Comment: @RadLexus That wouldn't be fair to ryyker who made valid points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an *[excerpt discussing content on encoding for Japanese language](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Encodings_And_Character_Display)*, created using Notepad++ (stated in comments as being used by OP)

> Double Byte encodings, also called, by usage, Double Byte Character
>   Set (DBCS)
>
> Some of them preexisted Unicode, and were designed to encode character
>   sets with a large number of characters, mainly found in Far East
>   languages with ideographic or syllabic scripts:
>
> ```
> The 2 Bytes Universal Character Set : UCS-2 Big Endian and UCS-2 Little Endian
> The Japanese Code Page : Shift-JIS ( Windows-932 )
> The Chinese Code Pages : Simplified Chinese GB2312 ( Windows-936 ),
> Traditionnal Chinese Big5 ( Windows-950 )
> The Korean Code Pages : Windows 949, EUC-KR
> ```

It would appear that Shift-JIS might be the encoding you are trying to read.
From *[here](https://www.google.com/#q=What+is+Shift+JIS)*

> Shift JIS (Shift Japanese Industrial Standards, also SJIS, MIME name
>   Shift_JIS) is a character encoding for the Japanese language,
>   originally developed by a Japanese company called ASCII Corporation in
>   conjunction with Microsoft...

In general, you need to determine the encoding used to create the multi-byte characters in a file, before they can be correctly read back out by a function in C, or any other language.  *[This link may help](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)*.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful to understand encoding. At the top of notepad++ there is an option for encoding that you can set. I'm using UTF-8.

Comment: Okay, the assumption I made in my post is incorrect then, but more importantly, you now know what your encoding is and should be able to make adjustments in your code to accommodate.

Comment: I tried changing the read mode for _wfopen to "r, ccs=UTF-8" and the buffer is correct but nothing is being printed to the console with my printf

Comment: I do not have time now to troublshoot, but I likely will later.  My approach will be to simply start with your code base (in post) and play with the discrete option sets in the function argurment. (I may even upload Notepad++ to test :) )  If I discover anything that will help, I will edit my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You read the file content and basically copied it into an allocated memory buffer.

But a key point is: what **encoding** is used to store the Japanese text in the file?

For example, if the text is encoded in UTF-8, you should convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 (using for example the MultiByteToWideChar Win32 API) , as you seem having a wchar_t buffer in memory.

If you are using a recent version of Visual Studio, you can also [specify some encoding information in the mode string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) passed to _wfopen_s (using the `ccs` flag).

**EDIT** Since you are printing the content of the read buffer using printf, make sure that the buffer is NUL-terminated.

Comment: There is no standard encoding for `wchar_t`. Modern systems use UTF-32, though. OP does not write he uses Windows.

Comment: @Olaf You're right that wchar_t is not clearly defined by the standard, but on Windows it's used for UTF-16, and OP's code seems Windows-specific.

Comment: How do I know what encoding my Japanese text file is in? I simply wrote Japanese text to it and saved it as a .txt. If the file is UTF-8, would that meen I set the locale to UTF-8? I don't understand the answer.

Comment: @Katianie You may want to tag your question with Windows then.

Comment: Well then ... But why transcode from one RLE code to another? Why not use UTF-8 already?

Comment: @Katianie - what device/software did you use to create the file.  It should have some information about what encoding it uses.

Comment: @Katianie You need to understand the differences between character set and encoding. Your editor should document the encoding it uses for text. Most common is UTF-8, as that is identical to ASCII for the first 128 codes.

Comment: @Olaf Can you please explain what you meen?

Comment: @ryyker its a simple windows text file i created and opened with notepad++.

Comment: @Katianie A file is a sequence of bytes. A text encoding specifies how those bytes are interpreted. You can store a Japanese text using several encodings, e.g. UTF-8 (most common these days), Shift-JIS, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, etc.

Comment: @KatianieIf you don't have access to google, use Wikipedia directly ...

Comment: @Mr.C64 So lets assume my file is in UTF-8, how would I go about fixing my issue? Do i set locale to "UTF-8"? I tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: @Katianie localisation is another different thing.

Comment: @Katianie Try using _wfopen_s specifying the UTF-8 encoding with the ccs flag, as I already wrote in the answer.

Comment: what is the syntax for that "r, css=UTF-8"?

Comment: @Katianie The syntax is explained in the MSDN doc. Please beware of typos: ccs not css.

Comment: If you would like me to accept you answer please provide the fix in your answer.

Comment: I gave all the information you need to fix your code. You may try to experiment with the ccs flag I suggested. I'm not going to write code for you.

Comment: I tried doing as you sugjusted by changing the mode for _wfopen to "r, ccs=UTF-8" but it still does not work.

Comment: @Katianie What doesn't work? What you actually got? Are you sure of the actual encoding used in your file?

Comment: Its getting the correct text in the buffer now but when I try to print it using printf("%S\n", buffer) nothing is being printed.

Comment: @Katianie Maybe the console isn't able to display the Japanese characters? Try using MessageBox instead of printf, e.g. `MessageBox(NULL, text, L"Test", MB_OK);`.

Comment: I'm curios why my answer that had 2 up votes was down voted to 0, considering I suggested the encoding problem, the ccs mode and the MessageBox as well.

Comment: @Mr.C64 - I just noticed the same thing. My up vote of your answer (which is a good answer, and which I clicked before I posted mine) is still in place.